# Including code using minted package inside an /ifthenelse block doesn't work in LATEX

Tags: latex

I'm trying to generate a general document and (using\ifthenelse) having different pdf versions. When I try to include a block of code using the minted package, the pdf is generated without the code.

The code is included if I try it outside the \ifthenelse block. Inside the block is the only place when is not working. Same happens with \lstset.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{ifthen}


\begin{document}

...

\newboolean{xcpp}

\setboolean{xcpp}{true}

\ifthenelse{xcpp}{

Test

\begin{listing}[ht] 
\begin{minted}{cpp}
int main() {
    int i=0;
    for (i=1; i<10; i++){
        int j=10;
        std::cout<<i<<" j: "<<j<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"\ni al salir del ciclo: "<<i; 
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\caption{Minimal working example}
\label{listing:1}
\end{listing}
}{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragile content such as code is always tricky inside the argument of another macro - but instead of trying to solve this problem, there is an easy workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newif\ifxcpp
\xcpptrue % <- comment this line to switch between the two versions

\ifxcpp
    \begin{listing}[ht] 
    \begin{minted}{cpp}
    int main() {
        int i=0;
        for (i=1; i<10; i++){
            int j=10;
            std::cout<<i<<" j: "<<j<<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout<<"\ni al salir del ciclo: "<<i; 
        return 0;
    }
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Minimal working example}
    \label{listing:1}
    \end{listing}
\else
    something else
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Now I'll try to replicate it into my main document. I'm trying to create notes where from a single source I could create versions for different programming languages.